# Writing a string to a text file not working?

Tags: c#, file-io

Im making a fun little project where i'm making a fake Garage sale POS system. its small right now and ill be adding more later. Right now i have the system ask you for the name of the Garage sale (event) and the dates on which they occur. Then it saves it to a text file. However it only saves the Words and not the variables 
is there something i'm doing wrong? thanks in advance!

Code:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using GarageSale.Domain;
  using System.IO;


 namespace GarageSaleConsoleApp
 {
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the AppTech GarageSale System! What is the name of your event?");
        Event _Event = new Event();

        String EventName = Console.ReadLine();

        EventName = _Event.Name;

        Console.WriteLine("Your event is called" + EventName + "Got it");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the date your event starts in this format MM/DD/YYYY");
        String DateStart = Console.ReadLine();

        DateStart = _Event.Date1;
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the date your event ends in this format MM/DD/YYYY");
        String DateEnd = Console.ReadLine();

        DateEnd = _Event.Date2;

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        Console.WriteLine("Your event Starts " + DateStart + "and ends " + DateEnd + "Got it");

        String[] EventInformation = { "Event Name:" + _Event.Name, "Event Dates", _Event.Date1 + " To " +  _Event.Date2, };

        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\\Users\\Jackson\\Desktop\\EventInfoAssignment1LHeller/EventInformation.txt", EventInformation);





        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use `Path.Combine()` over string concat to make legal file names

Comment: Hint: your assignments are the wrong way round - check what you do with the variables after the ReadLine calls.

Comment: When you do `x = y;` you are assigning *to* `x`, which means that `x` is the variable that is getting a new value, the thing on the right of the assignment operator, `y` in my case, is the thing that gives a value to be assigned. So when you do `EventName = _Event.Name;`, you're assigning *to* `EventName`. Apparently you meant to do the opposite, so swap the variables around, use `_Event.Name = EventName;`, or even just `_Event.Name = Console.ReadLine();`.

Comment: When you step through the code in the debugger and examine `_Event` what do you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the variables you are passing in correctly.

You are doing this:

```
String EventName = Console.ReadLine();

    EventName = _Event.Name;
```

You should be doing it like this:

```
String EventName = Console.ReadLine();

    _Event.Name = EventName;
```

Then fix the rest of the variables that are also wrong in the file.